# Why elements beyond canvas don't animated (fabricjs)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas, fabricjs

**Fabricjs:** I have some circles, beyond canvas layer **(top: -300)**, they have coords, but when I do animate to the specified position they just appearing on screen in specified duration without any animation. Why they do like so and what is the way to implement this?

```
animateCircle(ind, co, shift = -300, ca) {
    co.animate('top', shift, {
        duration: 1000,
        onChange: ind !== null && ++ind === ca.length ? this.c.renderAll.bind(this.c): undefined,
        easing: fabric.util.ease[0]
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on latest fabricjs there is a parameter to skip drawing of offscreen objects.
You have two ways to animate offscreen objects:

1) disable the skipOffscreen check setting `skipOffscreen` to false on the canvas, always or just for the animation duration.

2) during animation calculate obj.setCoords() for the animation object.

```
animateCircle(ind, co, shift = -300, ca) {
    co.animate('top', shift, {
        duration: 1000,
        onChange: ind !== null && ++ind === ca.length ? 
        function() {
          this.c.renderAll();
          co.setCoords();
        } : undefined,
        easing: fabric.util.ease[0]
    });
}
```